# How to stack data with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

Okay, so I have data with some large number of columns, say 400.

```
UID, ID, ID, var1, var2, . . . var400

1, 23,  4651,  0,     0, . . .   1
2, 47,  8567,  1,     1, . . .   5
```

I need it stacked so that it looks like this:

```
UID, ID, ID,    Variable,  Value
1,   23, 4651    var1,       0
1,   23, 4651    var2,       0
. . .
1,   23, 4651    var400,     1
2,   47, 8567,   var1        1
2,   47, 8567,   var2        1
. . . 
2,   47, 8567,   var400      5
```

There must be some relatively easy way to perform this transformation. But I can't think of what it is. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then take a look at [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start.

So I'm perhaps looking at something like

SELECT UID, ID, ID FROM 
    (SELECT UID, Var1, Var2 . . . Var400 from table) p
UNPIVOT
    (UID FOR ID IN
        (var1, var2 . . . var400)
     ) as unpivot

I'm unsure how to apply this documentation to my problem. Is that close?

Comment: ehm, I actually did post an answer with the static and dynamic version of the queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this will work for SQL Server 2005+. You have the static version of `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT UID, ID1, ID2, Variable, Value
FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable) T
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Variable IN (var1, var2, ....var400)) AS U;
```

**[Here is an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d1a7/1)** with a demo of this.

This will work, but you need to write every one of your 400 columns. If you don't want to do that (but I recommend that you do), you could extract the column names first and use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
                      AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'Var%'
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = '
SELECT UID, ID1, ID2, Variable, Value
FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable) T
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Variable IN ('+@cols+')) AS U;'

EXEC(@sql)
```

**[And here is an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d1a7/2)** with the dynamic version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES`:

```
select t.uid,
  t.id1,
  t.id2,
  c.variable,
  c.value
from YourTable t
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('var1', t.var1),
    ('var2', t.var2),
    ('var3', t.var3)
) c (variable, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d1a7/3) Thanks @Lamak for the fiddle